# Why not value it returne

Tags: php, fetch

I have an error when I do that :

> ```
> <?php 
>
> $mm = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=be','root',''); 
>
> $t = $all->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as nbm FROM tabl');
> echo $t->fetch()['nbm'];    
>
> // but when i put $h=$t->fetch(); echo $h['nbr'] ;it works .
> $t->closeCursor();
> ?>
> ```

Please can you explain why !!

Comment: [Array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102) is possible in PHP 5.4, which version are you using?

Comment: you can't access an array key of a function.

Comment: `I have an error` is not an error message. Give us the original error message.

Comment: @iamde_coder [yes, you can](https://eval.in/181171) (in PHP>=5.4)

Comment: @iamde_coder It is possible since PHP 5.4 (yes, exactly how he is trying to do). Maybe he isn't using PHP 5.4 yet.

Comment: my version of php is :5.3.10

Comment: You need at least PHP 5.4 in order to do it like you'd like to do it.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\mon site\ssss.php on line 4

Comment: but logically it is not fake

Answer (score 0):

You need at least PHP 5.4 to use [Array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102). If you don't have at least PHP 5.4, you have to do it with assigning a variable.

```
$mm = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=be','root',''); 

$t = $all->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as nbm FROM tabl');
$row = $t->fetch();    
echo $row['nbm'];

$t->closeCursor();
```